# Another way to use bs4UserCard in Shiny APP?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to do something similar to the figure that is attached. I saw an app that did this. The link to access this APP is:https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/lego-mosaic.html

A part where I manage to insert a small image of myself and tell a little about my ways of contact as it was done in the attached image. From what I saw they used package `shinyDashboard`, more precisely the `bs4UserCard`. In my case, I am not using this type of package. So, could you help me in this regard? Whoever knows how to do something similar doesn't have to be the same.

A other option would be something similar to image 2.

Code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                        title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                        
                        tabPanel("",
                                 
                                 div(
                                     style = 
                                         "height: 80px; background-color: #02BE7F; width: 100%; position: absolute; right:0;",
                                     h2(HTML("Project <b>Description</b>"), 
                                        style="text-align:center;color: white"),
                                     hr(),
                                     
                                     div(
                                         style = "width: 70%; margin: auto;",
                                         h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"), 
                                      style="text-align:justify")),
                                     tags$style(".navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}")
                                 )
                                 
                        ))



server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Option 1**
[image]

**Option 2**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this, haha, and it's responsive.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(
      style = "background: #f7f7f7; border-radius: 2px;",
      h2("Stackoverflow guy", style = "padding: 5px; padding-left: 20px"),
      fluidRow(
          column(
              3,
              tags$img(src = "https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/346-3462804_hd-quality-wallpaper-curly-hair-animals.jpg",
                       style = "border-radius: 50%; width: 75%; display: block; margin: 0 auto;"),
              tags$b("lz100", style = "width: 100%; display: block; text-align: center; font-size: 2rem;")
          ),
          column(
              9, style = "font-size: 2rem;",
              "bla bla bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla
              bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
              bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla."
          )
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]